# How to properly close SQLiteConnection object for database?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

**abc.db' was leaked!**

```
var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
var cursor: Cursor? = null
try {
   
   db = getReadWriteDB()

   val query = "Select * From Table"

   cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

 } catch (e: Exception) {

   e.printStackTrace()

 } finally {

   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {

      cursor.close()

   }

   if(db != null && db.isOpen()) {

     db.close()

   }
}
```

**Below is warning Text display.**

Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    try {

       db = getReadWriteDB()
       val query = "Select * From Table"
       cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

     } catch (e: Exception) {    
       e.printStackTrace()    
     } finally {    
    //     First close the cursor
       if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {    
          cursor.close()    
       }
    //     second close the database

       if (db != null && db.isOpen) {
           db.close()
    //     Release the database reference
           db.releaseReference()
       }
    }
```

close your db object

```
db.close()
```

below method is completely close your db references

```
db.releaseReference()
```

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, instead of just posting snippets, either add comments to them or add a brief explanation of your code, so people can have more understanding easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your second `if condition`.

Here is the updated code,

```
var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
var cursor: Cursor? = null
try {

   db = getReadWriteDB()

   val query = "Select * From Table"

   cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

 } catch (e: Exception) {

   e.printStackTrace()

 } finally {

   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
      cursor.close()
   }

   if(db != null && db.isOpen()) {
     db.close()
   }
}
```